# Add a taxonomy term to many vocabularies

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Is there is any way to add one term to many vocabularies with the same name and same id in drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. It's always one to one relationship between vocabulary and term...

If you see taxonomy_term_data table which stores term id and vocabulary id reference below..

[image]

tid is primary key which means always unique. So, you can't have another row which points to different vid.

Below schema definition in taxonomy.install confirms same..

```
  $schema['taxonomy_term_data'] = array(
    'description' => 'Stores term information.',
    'fields' => array(
      'tid' => array(
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique term ID.',
      ),
      'vid' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
        'description' => 'The {taxonomy_vocabulary}.vid of the vocabulary to which the term is assigned.',
      ),
      'name' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
        'description' => 'The term name.',
        'translatable' => TRUE,
      ),
      'description' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'size' => 'big',
        'description' => 'A description of the term.',
        'translatable' => TRUE,
      ),
      'format' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'description' => 'The {filter_format}.format of the description.',
      ),
      'weight' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
        'description' => 'The weight of this term in relation to other terms.',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('tid'),
    'foreign keys' => array(
      'vocabulary' => array(
        'table' => 'taxonomy_vocabulary',
        'columns' => array('vid' => 'vid'),
      ),
    ),
    'indexes' => array(
      'taxonomy_tree' => array('vid', 'weight', 'name'),
      'vid_name' => array('vid', 'name'),
      'name' => array('name'),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: then do you think there is another way to refer to one term in more than one vocabulary with the same name but with different id

Comment: Please ask as a different question...

Comment: Thanks .. i did and here is the link for the new question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/113194/one-taxonomy-term-in-multiple-vocabularies