# One taxonomy term in multiple vocabularies

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Is there is a way to refer to one term in more than one vocabulary?

e.g. i have 2 vocabularies ... Properties for sale and Properties for rent

Properties for sale:
**-Apartment**
-House
-Land
Properties for rent:
**-Apartment**
-summer house
-Room

So, how can i have the term (Apartment) in both vocabulary

Answer (score 1):

Well you could combine them in a single vocabulary and then your term can have two parents:

Properties
-Properties for sale
--Apartment
--House
--Land
-Properties for rent
--Apartment
--summer house
--Room